# How to relocate SQL Server Database file to external drive

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to MS SQL Server 2008.

I have a database back up which I've restored using MSSMS.  SO right now the database file is running somewhere from my localhost.  Is there a way for me to move the database file to an external drive and have it run from there?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to detach the database, move the mdf and ldf files to the external database, then attach the database.

Any reason why you want to run a database off of an external drive? The performance will suffer.

Comment: Performance will not necessarily suffer - there are eSATA drives and RAID enclosures which can deliver just as much as similar internal drive configuration. But reliability might - disconnecting an external drive is so much more easy.